# Проект Эйлера, задача №8

Tags: python

Найдите наибольшее произведение тринадцати последовательных цифр в данном числе.

```
    number = 7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450

multiplier = 1
mylist = []

for i in range(len(str(number))):
    thirteen = (list(str(number)[i:i + 13]))
    if '0' not in thirteen:
        for j in range(13):
            multiplier = multiplier * (int(thirteen[j]))
            mylist.append(multiplier)
print(max(mylist))
```

После того, как разбил исходное число на отрезки по 13 последовательных и исключил все последовательности, содержащие 0 (произведение которых очевидно будет равно нулю), возникает проблема с поиском итогового произведения. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Comment: А разбивать-то нафига? просто иди по строке. Есть у тебя произведение... множишь на следующую цифирь, делишь на первую - получаешь произведение для следующей группы. Если оно больше текущего - запоминаешь индекс. Если оно ноль - смещаешься сразу на 13 позиций.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
number = 7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450

multiplier = 1
mylist = []

for i in range(len(str(number))):
    thirteen = (list(str(number)[i:i + 13]))
    if '0' not in thirteen:
        multiplier=1    #тут нужно сбросить значение multiplier
        for j in range(13):
            multiplier = multiplier * (int(thirteen[j]))
            #print(multiplier)
            mylist.append(multiplier)
print(max(mylist))
```

вы multiplier не "обнуляете" после расчёта. и все новые значения просто домножаются.

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение Вашей задачи:

```
# Наибольшее произведение четырех последовательных цифр в нижеприведенном 1000-значном числе равно 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.
n=7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
diapazon=13
massiv=[]
stroka=list(str(n))
# Переводим большое число в список
for i in stroka:
    massiv.append(int(i))
# Превращаем каждый элемент строки в интежер
otv=0
for i in range(1, (len(massiv)-diapazon+2), 1):
    rez1 = 1
    for j in range(i-1, i+diapazon-1, 1):
        rez1=rez1*massiv[j]
    if rez1>otv:
        otv=rez1
        index_max=j
print("Наибольшее произведение", diapazon, "последовательных чисел: ", otv)
posl=[]
for k in range(index_max-diapazon+1, index_max+1, 1):
    posl.append(massiv[k])
print("Сама последовательность имеет вид: ", posl)
```

А если Вашим вариантом, то:

```
number = 7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450

multiplier = 1
mylist = []

for i in range(len(str(number))):
    thirteen = (list(str(number)[i:i + 13]))
    if '0' not in thirteen:
        multiplier=1
        for j in range(13):
            multiplier = multiplier * (int(thirteen[j]))
            mylist.append(multiplier)
print(max(mylist))
```

Answer (score 0):

**вариант 1 (решение в лоб):**

```
text = str(number)

res = 0
for i in range(len(text) - 13):
    p = 1
    for j in range(13):
        p *= int(text[i + j])

    if p > res:
        res = p

print(res)
```

**вариант 2 (однострочный):**

```
import math

text = str(number)

res = max(math.prod(map(int, text[i:i + 13])) for i in range(len(text) - 13))

print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(str(number))): # нужно до len()-13
    thirteen = (list(str(number)[i:i + 13])) # не ошибка, но list() не требуется
    if '0' not in thirteen:
        for j in range(13):
            # multiplier никогда не сбрасывается, и поэтому в нем содержится непонятно что
            multiplier = multiplier * (int(thirteen[j]))
            # не ошибка, но нет необходимости создавать отдельный список для произведений.
            # Достаточно сравнить текущий результат и максимум из предыдущих                
            mylist.append(multiplier) 

print(max(mylist))
```